# Creating a hyperlink in oracle tables

Tags: oracle, hyperlink

My requirement is in a word document we can create a hyper link to a file and on clicking the link the Respective file can be opened. In case of oracle i am storing the location of a file into a table and is there any possibility to open that file by clicking on it?

Example: the file is in the location 
"d:/test/test.pdf" is stored in the table. On clicking the value is it possible to open the file?

Comment: Clicking on it where? From a client, an application you've written, ...? I'm not aware of any clients what would support that (e.g. from a grid view), but saying which client you're using would be useful anyway.

Comment: The Oracle database doesn't care at all about the behaviour of the link. It's solely your application's task to offer such a hyperlink to the user.

Comment: And by the way, a link to file in the local file system can obviously only work on that PC where the file system resides.